# Wrong console output in Threadfunc using mutex

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, console, mutex

I try to implement a so-called "Mikado" game using Mutex for the first time and I have problems with the output after the termination flag for the Mutex section has been set.

Here's is the code if somebody wants to have a closer look for it:

http://fpaste.org/95304/54333139/

After the termination flag has been set I release the mutex and return 0 from my threadfunc. But the other remeaning two threads still go into the while loop and make the wrong outputs. Why is that so? And how do I have to change that?

After the termination has been set the other two threads have to make the prints that they have lost the game but it first shows that they won and then that they lost the game.

> Player #0 removed 3 sticks.
>                   and wins!!!
>   Player #1 removed 0 sticks.
>                   and wins!!!
>   Player #2 removed 0 sticks.
>                   and wins!!!
>   Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .

If i add in the else part (!gTermination)

```
        else if(!gTermination)
            {
                cout << "  \n       and wins!!!" << endl;
                gTermination=true;
                ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
                return 0;

            }
```

then the output is almost true, because the other two threads still go into the while loop:

> Player #2 botched his chance... - Nothing removed.
>   Player #0 removed 3 sticks.
>                   and wins!!!
>   Player #1 removed 0 sticks.
>   Game over - I, Player #1 lost...
>   Player #2 removed 0 sticks.
>   Game over - I, Player #2 lost...
>   Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .

So why do the other two threads still go into the loop although the termination flag has been set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop starts like this:

```
while(!gTermination)
{
    DWORD res=WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE); 
    ...
}
```

So each player is blocking on `hMutex`, then you set the flag to true, then you release `hMutex`, so they finish their loops. A simple fix would be something like this:

```
while(!gTermination)
{
    DWORD res=WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE);
    if(gTermination)
    {
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works, but it's still not clear to me why the other two threads don't know the latest state of gTermination (that it has been set to true) and still have to finish their loops. Would you be so kind and describe it again in other words?

Comment: Your flow looks like this: If not terminated, wait for a mutex, then run a bunch of code. If you flip the termination flag while they are waiting for the mutex, there is nothing in your code that tells them to immediately terminate.